# How to set a react use state array from onSelectAll checkbox in react bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I have a table with multiple rows and each row has a corresponding checkbox. Currently when I check a checkbox I have a use state array that updates with a name from the row. i.e if I have a table with three rows, Bob, Jon, Joe, and each name has a checkbox next to it, upon the checkbox being clicked the name enters into the array.

```
const handleAdd = (fileRow) => {
        setSelectedFileRows([...selectedFileRows, fileRow]);
    };
    const handleRemove = (fileRow) => {
        const newFiles = selectedFileRows.filter((t) => t !== fileRow);
        setSelectedFileRows(newFiles);
    };
    const selectRow = {
        mode: "checkbox",
        style: { backgroundColor: "#c8e6c9" },
        onSelect: (row, isSelect) => {
            if (isSelect) {;
                handleAdd(row.name);
            } else {
                handleRemove(row.name);
            }
        }
```

This all works fine and dandy but when I try to populate the array with onSelectAll where one checkbox gets clicked and all the rows are likewise checked off, the array does not populate properly.

```
onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows) => {
            if (isSelect) {
                rows.forEach((row) => {
                    handleAdd(row.name);
                });
            } else {
                rows.forEach((item) => {
                    handleRemove(item.name);
                });
            }
        }
```

I've seen that I'm not supposed to update a use state in a loop but I am new to this and dont really see a way to get all the names to populate an array.

Comment: wouldn't you just `setSelectedFileRows([...allRows])` or what ever the name of the array that holds all your rows is?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that with `useState`, when you do `setX`, it doesn't actually update `X` until the next render.  So when you add/remove in a loop, you will constantly be looking at the initial state from the current render.

The trick, is to add everything / remove everything all at once, I would do it like this:

```
const handleAdd = (fileRows) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(fileRows)) {
        fileRows = [fileRows];
    }
    setSelectedFileRows([...selectedFileRows, ...fileRows]);
};
const handleRemove = (fileRows) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(fileRows)) {
        fileRows = [fileRows];
    }
    const newFiles = selectedFileRows.filter((t) => !fileRows.includes(t));
    setSelectedFileRows(newFiles);
};

onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows) => {
    if (isSelect) {
        handleAdd(rows.map(r => r.name));
    } else {
        handleRemove(rows.map(r => r.name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this: fileRows = [fileRows]; It causes a no param reassign linting error, just want to understand the logic of this (im new to react)

Comment: It's just turning it into an array if it's not already an array (which lets you pass in a single item or a set of items, and it works either way).  Not really necessary if you just always pass in an array, but I like being able to do either